# FirebaseDatabase runTransaction block issue

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm struggling with updating multiple `FirebaseDatabase` nodes in a `runTransactionBlock`. This block should increment the `likesCount` and the `recordsCount`. Initially, when a post is made, those are set to 0. So, I'm checking if the `likesCount == 0`, if it is, the this means that's the first like of the post so it simply sets the `likes` array with the userUid and a value of `true` in a separate node. Then increment the `likesCount` and `recordsCount` in this node and `runTransactionBlock` to update their values. First time around, this works. It sets their values.

```
func incrementLikes(postId: String, onSuccess: @escaping (Post) -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {

    let postRef = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.child(postId)

    postRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData) -> TransactionResult in
        if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

            var likesCount = post["likesCount"] as? Int ?? 0
            var recordsCount = post["recordsCount"] as?  Int ?? 0

            if likesCount == 0 { // First like for the post

               // add self in posts_likes > postId > likes
               // increment likes count & increment records Count
                Api.Posts_Likes.firstPostsLikes(postId: postId)
                likesCount += 1
                recordsCount += 1
            }
            else {
                Api.Posts_Likes.setPostsLikes(postId: postId, onSuccess: { (isPostLiked) in  // checks if user liked the post or not, if he did, his id was added in posts_likes > likes

                    if isPostLiked {
                        likesCount += 1
                        recordsCount += 1
                    }
                    else {
                        likesCount -= 1
                        recordsCount -= 1
                    }

                }, onError: { (errMessage) in
                    onError(errMessage)
                })
            }

            post["recordsCount"] = recordsCount as AnyObject?
            post["likesCount"] = likesCount as AnyObject?

            currentData.value = post

            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    })
    { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            onError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let dict = snapshot?.value as? [String: Any] {
            let post = Post.transformDataToImagePost(dictionary: dict, key: snapshot!.key)
            onSuccess(post)
        }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the button again, then it goes in the `else` statement, since `likesCount` is not equal to `0` anymore. This is where it's not working. When `Api.Posts_Likes.setPostsLikes(postId: postId, onSuccess:)` is called, it should return a `Bool` value whether or not the user has liked or unliked the post. Based on that `bool` value, it should `increment` or `decrement` the `likesCount` & the `recordsCount` in the `posts` node. But it doesn't and I don't get why.

```
  func firstPostsLikes(postId: String) {
        guard let currentUser = Api.Users.CURRENT_USER else { return }

    REF_POSTS_LIKES.child(postId).child("likes").child(currentUser.uid).setValue(true)

}

func setPostsLikes(postId: String, onSuccess: @escaping (Bool) -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {

    let postLikesRef = Api.Posts_Likes.REF_POSTS_LIKES.child(postId)
    guard let currentUser = Api.Users.CURRENT_USER else { return }
    var userLikedPost: Bool = false

    postLikesRef.runTransactionBlock ({ (currentPostsLikesData) -> TransactionResult in

        if var postLikes = currentPostsLikesData.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            var likes = postLikes["likes"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]

            if let _ = likes[currentUser.uid] {
                // Unlike the post and remove self from likes
                likes.removeValue(forKey: currentUser.uid)
                userLikedPost = false
            }
            else {
                // Like the post, add self to posts_likes, increase likesCount & recordsCount
                likes[currentUser.uid] = true
                userLikedPost = true
            }

            postLikes["likes"]  = likes as AnyObject

            currentPostsLikesData.value = postLikes

            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentPostsLikesData)
        }
        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentPostsLikesData)
    })
    { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error  {
            onError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
            onSuccess(userLikedPost)
    }
```

This is what the `FirebaseDatabase` looks like:

[image]

The `recordsCount` in the `posts` node is total sum of the `commentsCount`, `likesCount`, `repostsCount` and `applaudsCount`. The only thing I need to display when a new `post` is loaded in a cell is the `recordsCount`. That's why I don't want to put all arrays of likes, applauds, comments, etc under the post itself because it will download enormous amount of data for nothing UNLESS the user clicks on the `recordsCount` button to actually